# Cooldown in every Commands

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Why my command still not getting a cooldown when user used it?

Here's the code:

```
    const cooldown = new Set();
  const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
  const eco = require('discord-mongoose-economy');
  eco.connect("mongodb://localhost/database"); //this is not the main I hide it
  const work = require('../../events/casino/work.json')
  

  if(cooldown.has(message.author.id)) {
    message.reply(`You're tired! Wait for 30 seconds to work again!`)
  } else {
  const total = Object.keys(work).length
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * total + 1);
  var workInfo = work[random];
  const min = 10;
  const max = 100;
  const coin = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;

  if(message.author.bot) return;

  await eco.give(message.author.id, message.guild.id, coin);
    const workembed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(workInfo.description + `and recieved ` + coin + ` coins`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setFooter({text: `Work #${random}`}) 

    message.channel.send({embeds: [workembed]});
  }
    cooldown.add(message.author.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      cooldown.delete(message.author.id)
    }, 30000);
```

Is there any misplaced codes or something? Because there's still no cooldown, I'm using discord.js v13

I've edited my codes to this:

```
if(cooldown.has(message.author.id)) {
    message.reply(`You're tired! Wait for 30 seconds to work again!`)
  } else {
  const total = Object.keys(work).length
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * total + 1);
  var workInfo = work[random];
  const min = 10;
  const max = 100;
  const coin = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;

  if(message.author.bot) return;

  await eco.give(message.author.id, message.guild.id, coin);
    const workembed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(workInfo.description + `and recieved ` + coin + ` coins`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setFooter({text: `Work #${random}`}) 

    message.channel.send({embeds: [workembed]});

    cooldown.add(message.author.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
      cooldown.delete(message.author.id)
    }, 30000);
  }
```

Still not working.

Last edit for my command and its finally working, I added a package called `humanize-duration` here is the final code of my work:

```
    const cooldowns = new Map();
    const humanizeDuration = require('humanize-duration');
    const cooldown = cooldowns.get(message.author.id);
  if(cooldown) {
    const remaining = humanizeDuration(cooldown - Date.now(), {units: ['s'], round: true})
    const cd = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,name: `${message.member.user.tag}`})
    .setDescription(`You need to wait ${remaining} to do work again, take some rest!`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    return message.channel.send({embeds: [cd]})
    .catch(console.error);
  } else {
    const total = Object.keys(work).length
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * total + 1);
    var workInfo = work[random];
    const min = 80000;
    const max = 120000;
    const coin = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
  
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    await eco.give(message.author.id, message.guild.id, coin);
    const workembed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`,name: `${message.member.user.tag}`})
    .setDescription(workInfo.description + `and recieved ` + coin + ` coins`)
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setFooter({text: `Work #${random}`}) 

    message.channel.send({embeds: [workembed]});

    cooldowns.set(message.author.id, Date.now() + 30000);
    setTimeout(() => cooldowns.delete(message.author.id), 30000);
    }
```

If someone need this code I hope you guys can get some tips!

Comment: Did you make sure the `setTimeout` is executed (e.g by logging) and that the values you give to your cooldown `add` and `delete` methods are valid values (not undefined or null)?

Comment: The methods are not giving any errors :/